# Comment reporting for Multisite

Tags: multisite, comments, plugin-recommendation

I'm trying out the two comment reporting plugins that I know about in a multisite installation.

- [AJAX Report Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/report-comments/)
- [Safe Report Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/safe-report-comments/)

Both don't work - various javascript errors and (I assume) not taking into account the differences between single and multisite WP.

Does anyone know of a working comment reporting plugin for Multisite, or has anyone run into issues with the above plugins before?

**[Update]**

Using Ajax Report Comments

- Clicking on the "Report comment" link correctly opens a textbox.
- Clicking on the "Report comment" button (which should fire off the report) raises the following error in chrome's javascript console

  ```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
    mysack.onCompletion
    runAJAX.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
  ```

The inserted javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function reportComment( commentID )
{
  var reporter_comment = document.getElementById( 'reportcomment_comment_textarea_' + commentID ).value;
  var mysack = new sack( 'http://test-staffblogs.nature.com/news/wp-content/plugins/report-comments/report.php?c='+commentID+'&r='+escape(reporter_comment) );

  mysack.method = 'POST';
  mysack.onError    = function() { alert( "Error Error Error" ) };
  mysack.onCompletion = function() { finishReport( commentID, eval( '(' + this.response + ')' )); }

  mysack.runAJAX();
}

function reportComment_AddTextArea( commentID )
{
    document.getElementById( 'reportcomment_results_div_' + commentID ).innerHTML = "Why are you doing this?";
    var textarea = "<textarea name=\"reportcomment_comment_textarea_" + commentID + "\" id=\"reportcomment_comment_textarea_" + commentID + "\" cols=\"55\" rows=\"4\" class=\"reportcomment_textarea\"></textarea><br /><input type=\"button\" name=\"Report Comment\" value=\"Report Comment\" onclick=\"reportComment( " + commentID + " );\" />";
    document.getElementById( 'reportcomment_comment_div_' + commentID ).innerHTML = textarea;
}

function finishReport( commentID, response )
{
    var message = '<span class="reportedcomment_text">'+response.message+'</span>';
    document.getElementById( 'reportcomment_results_div_' + commentID ).innerHTML = message;

        document.getElementById( 'reportcomment_comment_div_' + commentID ).innerHTML = '';
        }
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Are they in `wp-content/mu-plugins` (auto-run) or just `wp-content/plugins`, then activated in admin?

Comment: @thedeadmedic The latter - ie in wp-content/plugins

Comment: Could you elaborate on the JS errors? Check the source and make sure `safe-report-comments/js/ajax.js` is loaded in the `<head />` (applies to Safe Report).

Comment: @thedeadmedic - updated with the javascript error from Ajax Report Comments

Comment: What happens with Safe Report?

Comment: @thedeadmedic, I've stopped using it, it looks even more broken for multisite than Ajax Report Comments - some searching shows that it's not multisite aware, so doesn't take the blog id into account

Comment: Can you post the script inside `<head />` that gets generated by AR? Should be functions like `reportComment( commentID )` etc.

Comment: @thedeadmedic - added

Comment: Well this is fun. Googling the 'token' error garners numerous, inconclusive answers.  I just installed it myself - the AJAX fires fine, but chokes on undefined function `die`. IMHO this plugin isn't written well, and you'd be better off moving on. I'd say give 'Report Comments' by Dagon Design a go (not in plugin directory).

Comment: @thedeadmedic - tried your suggested plugin (I'd seen it before but avoided it as it only states 2.8 compatibility). Anyway, it seems to be working - so thanks! Leave an answer and I'll accept, if you want.

Comment: Glad to hear it does the job, though I'll leave it at that - I don't feel it's worthy of an 'answer' ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Copy from comment to make the solution appear in our search results)*

Use the [Report Comments Plugin](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/report-comments-plugin-for-wordpress/) from Dagon Design.